# Google Image Ad goes outside the parent div

Tags: html, css

The Google Ad in my sidebar is extending outside the parent div and overlaps the other content.

Here's a screenshot of the problem I have:

[image]

The Google Adwords code is defined within a  that is included within the  with the 'sidebar' id:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div>
        <h3>Categorías</h3>
        [categories defined here]
    </div>
    <div>
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        [rest of google adwords code here]
    </div>
</div>
```

And here it is the relevant css:

```
#sidebar {
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    padding:10px;
    height:100%;
}
```

I've tried adding `'overflow:hidden'` in the `#sidebar` div, but it doesn't work either, the Google ad gets cropped but I want it to fit into the sidebar.

What do I need to change to make the ad fit inside it's parent div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the css that is placing the elements in your sidebar, my guess is that your ad position is set to float because it is not being contained within the sidebar div.

In that case, you need to implement [Clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/):

**1. Create the clearfix class in CSS:**

Add the following CSS (Note: this it works for IE8 and higher. If you need to support older browsers, check the link above).

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

**2. Apply the clearfix to your HTML:**

Add the clearfix class to the div that holds your ad:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    [...]
    <div class="clearfix">
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        [rest of google adwords code here]
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note**:

It might not be the div that is floating, in that case you will need to check the elements using element inspector. You can't add classes to elements that are part of the Google ad, so instead you can change the CSS rule to use the class name or ID of the element that is floating.

**Reference**:

Clearfix: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: You pointed me into the right direction! I have to use the class you suggested, but in the div containing the categories, not in the one containing the google ad ... thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! As I said, without seeing the rest of the code, I couldn't tell which but I knew it was one of them :-)